# How can I add my workers to my Kubernetes cluster I created with kubeadm?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubeadm

I have three VMS I created with vagrant that can communicate with each other. Following through a video and also K8s official documentation on creating a cluster with kubeadmn. The master node has been created and it works well. I can run kubectl commands from the master and I get no issue.

[Screenshot of kubectl command running in my master node.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7SD2.png)

The conatinerd service is running on all nodes.

[Screenshot showing my containerd service running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mfZD.png)

Also, the three VMS are all connected, such that if I ping the master node from any of the worker nodes it works.

[Screenshot showing the output of the ping connection between worker 2 and master node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNRTX.png)

Whenever I run the kubeadm join command from the workers I keep getting errors.

The command I used to generate join tokens is

```
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

This is the command I run on my worker nodes, the command is the output from the above command.

```
sudo kubeadm join 192.168.56.2:6443 --token wy4gwu.dhelq16icewvajmn --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:9454f2120c1b43219782debb39ce65fb4d0e475f3969ddc20bd12b8d2676883c --v
```

This is the error I keep getting;

[This is the screenshot of the errors gotten when the worker node wants to join the cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPKWF.jpg)

Please is there anything I am doing wrong, how can I add my workers to the Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy&paste. You are just making it harder to extract information.